# Is it okay to create new Instance of picasso everytime

Tags: android, out-of-memory, picasso

Is it okay to create a new instace of picasso for loading every image.For E.g something like:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .centerInside(
    .tag(context)
    .into(holder.image);
```

in `getView()` of a `listAdaptor`.Does it not create new `LruCache` everytime which will eventually lead to OOM.

Also can the `Context` passed to Picasso can be an `Activity Context`:

```
/** Start building a new {@link Picasso} instance. */
public Builder(Context context) {
  if (context == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
  }
  this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Picasso is designed to be a singleton, so there's isn't a new instance created every time.

This is the `with()` method :

```
public static Picasso with(Context context) {
    if (singleton == null) {
      synchronized (Picasso.class) {
        if (singleton == null) {
          singleton = new Builder(context).build();
        }
      }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

Note that it is a static method so you don't call `with()` on a particular instance, Picasso is managing its own instance, which is only created if `singleton` is `null`.

There's no problem with passing an `Activity` as the context, because the `Builder` will use the ApplicationContext which is a `single, global Application object of the current process` :

```
public Builder(Context context) {
      if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
      }
      this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

As for the cache, the same one is use everytime, since it is retained by the singleton :

```
public Picasso build() {
      // code removed for clarity

      if (cache == null) {
        cache = new LruCache(context);
      }
      // code removed for clarity

      return new Picasso(context, dispatcher, cache, listener, transformer, requestHandlers, stats,
          defaultBitmapConfig, indicatorsEnabled, loggingEnabled);
}
```

Comment: I want to stress the `single, global Application object of the current process`. This means that you will need to have one instance of Picasso for each one of the processes that your app is running upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
Its not problem..You are not creating Object
```

`Picasso` is already `SingleTon` Object

Here is the Souce code Picasso Class

```
public static Picasso with(Context context) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        synchronized (Picasso.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new Builder(context).build();
            }
        }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

More Source code at [Picasso Source code](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java)

Answer (score 1):

Kalyan is right! Picasso is already a singleton, so it uses the same instance for all the images that you load. Also that means that you will not need that builder. you simply just call:
"Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.image);" with the settings you want and that is all.